# Doctrine, editing ManyToMany - Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

lets suppose I have something like this

```
class Menu extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity {

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MenuItem", mappedBy="menus")
 **/
protected $menuItems;

function __construct() {
    $this->menuItems = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

and this

```
class MenuItem extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity {
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu", inversedBy="menuItems")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cms_menuMenuItems")
 */
protected $menus;

public function __construct() {
    $this->menus = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Now when I want do something like this in code

```
$menu->menuItems->add( $menuItem );
```

I get error about $menu->menuItems is not a Object ( when I dump menu, it says menuItems property is an PersistendCollection)
When i dump $menu->menuItems, I find $menuItems property is an array. Ok, then I want to push into it

```
$menu->menuItems[] = $menuItem;
```

but nothing happens, I get following PHP Notice:
    **Indirect modification of overloaded property**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you declared `$menuItems` as `protected`. To access it you should create a getter (if you are calling it outside the class, which you don't specify, but i'm guessing it):

```
public function getMenuItems() {
    return $this->menuItems;
}
```

and then to add a MenuItem:

```
$menu->getMenuItems()->add($item);
```